# Syntax for plotting three points' movement using FuncAnimation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot

My code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

def animate(i):
    ax.set_data(ax.scatter(ptx1, pty1, ptz1, c='red'),
        ax.scatter(ptx2, pty2, ptz2, c='blue'),
        ax.scatter(ptx3, pty3, ptz3, c='green'))

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=10, interval=200)

plt.show()
```

I'm trying to plot the movement of three points. Each ptx/y/z/1/2/3 is a list of floats giving the coordinates of the point. I'm just not sure how to use FuncAnimation to animate my points. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you get any error when you run this?

Comment: `FuncAnimations` (with `frames=10`) calls `animate` 10-times. Every time it is called you have to change data. This way you get animation. `i` is current frame number so you can use it to get different data from list.

Comment: So should I try a for loop iterating through my lists within animate?

Comment: And yes, @Achilles. the Axes3d library doesn't have any attribute 'set_data.' I'm kind of mixing up the two right now

Comment: To add to the list of things that didn't work: 'def animate(i):
  for i in range(len(ptx1)):
   ax.scatter(ptx1[i], pty1[i], ptz1[i], c='red')
   ax.scatter(ptx2[i], pty2[i], ptz2[i], c='blue')
   ax.scatter(ptx3[i], pty3[i], ptz3[i], c='green')'

Comment: no, now you add all elements in every call - so you can't see difference. You have to use only one element in every call (ie. `ax.scatter(ptx1[i], pty1[i], ptz1[i], c='red')` without `for`)  or add one element to displayed data. Create minimal working example in question so everyone could run it and then we can show working example with modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example. `animate` is called many times and everytime you have to use different data to see animation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random

# create some random data    
ptx1 = [random.randint(0,100) for x in range(20)]
pty1 = [random.randint(0,100) for x in range(20)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

def animate(i):
    # use i-th elements from data
    ax.scatter(ptx1[:i], pty1[:i], c='red')

    # or add only one element from list
    #ax.scatter(ptx1[i], pty1[i], c='red')

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=20, interval=500)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @furas! This was exactly what I needed. I wasn't picking from the ith element so it wasn't working